# Div "swal2-container" is still visible after using swal2 with redirect and going back

Tags: redirect, sweetalert2

I am using swal2 to get a confirm dialog on a page (sourcepage.html) after clicking on a link before redirecting to another page (targetpage.html).
This works well so far.
However, after being redirected to targetpage.html and want to go back using the browsers "back-button" to sourcepage.html, the page is "darkened" and not usable anymore and this is because the
`<div class="swal2-container .....>` is still there and covers the page completely.
If I hit "reload" on that page, the container is gone.

Here´s my current code:

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="JSconfirm()">Redirect me to targetpage.html</a>
```

JS

```
function JSconfirm(){
swal.fire({
title: "Redirect",
type: "warning",
html: "Here comes custom text with html",
showCancelButton: true,
closeOnConfirm: true,
closeOnCancel: true,
confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
cancelButtonText: "No",
confirmButtonText: "Yes"
}).then(function (result) {
 if (result.value) {
    window.location = "targetpage.html";
 }
 });
}
```

What can I do to make sure that this div isn´t visible anymore. It should be "deleted" from sourcepage.html after clicking "yes" to confirm to be redirected to "targetpage.html".

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself

Adding swal.close and a timeout before the redirect did the trick.

```
}).then(function (result) {
 if (result.value) {
    swal.close();
   setTimeout (
   () => {
    window.location.href  = "targetpage.html";
},
  1 * 500
);
}});
}
```